# How to copy and inject the main-bower-files in one step using gulp?

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

When deploying my app I want to copy the bower dependency to the `deploy` directory and inject the links to these files into the `index.html` that is also in the `deploy` directory.

Each step alone works perfectly by I'm not able to combine them.

Copy the files:

```
return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), { read: false })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./deploy/lib/'));
```

Injecting the files:

```
return gulp.src('./deploy/index.html')
    .pipe(plugins.inject(
        gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), { read: false }), { relative: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./deploy/'));
```

I think that I should do this in one step to keep the correct order of the dependent files.

I tried this combination but it did not work out.

```
return gulp.src('./deploy/index.html')
    .pipe(plugins.inject(
        gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), { read: false })
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./deploy/lib/'), { relative: true })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./deploy/'));
```

Answer (score 13):

I recommend [wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep):

You add a block to your html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <!-- endbower -->
</body>
</html>
```

and your wiredep task looks like:

```
// inject bower components
gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
  var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
  gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(wiredep())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});
```

Which will add the deps to your html as such:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="bower_components/foo/bar.js"></script>
  <!-- endbower -->
</body>
</html>
```

You can then combine this with [useref](https://github.com/jonkemp/gulp-useref) to order all your project's javascript dependencies

html block

```
<!-- build:js scripts/app.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/foo/bar.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<script src="js/yourcustomscript.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

gulp task

```
gulp.task('html', ['styles'], function () {
  var assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: '{.tmp,app}'});

  return gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(assets)
    .pipe(assets.restore())
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Take a look at how generator-gulp-webapp does things: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp

Note: the `$.plugin` syntax assumes `var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();`

Comment: Where does this `'app'` variable come from?